# Show that $F+G$ is closed when $G$ a closed subspace of normed space $E$ and $F$ a finite dimensional subspace of $E$.

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

**Question: Let $E$ be a normed space. Let $G$ be a closed subspace of $E$ and let $F$ be a finite dimensional subspace of $E$. Show that $F+G$ is a subspace of $E$ and is closed.**

I'm having trouble in showing $F+G$ to be closed. I know that $F$ is itself closed and complete, as it is a finite dimensional subspace of a normed space, and that if $F$ were compact that $G+F$ would be closed. I also know that the closed unit ball of any finite dimensional normed space is compact.

I tried two methods. One was to take a convergent sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ in $G+F$. Then we can write $x_n = f_n + g_n$ where $f_n$ and $g_n$ are sequences in $F$ and $G$ respectively, and I attempted to find a way to force the individual components $f_n$ and $g_n$ inside the unit ball which would enable me to say that they had convergent subsequences. I couldn't see how to do this, however.

The other thought was to try and show that $F$ is compact, but I don't see a way to do this as I can't imagine it to be simply true without some other conditions on $F$.

Are one of these methods the right way to go? Or should I go another direction? I would appreciate any help I can get, although I would prefer not to be presented with a full proof so that I can do some work for myself. Thanks!

Comment: You are right that $F$ is not compact: an easy example is $\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to prove it is to consider the quotient $E/G$. Let $\pi$ be the canonical map. Then $\pi(F) \subset E/G$ is finite-dimensional, hence closed ($E/G$ is Hausdorff since $G$ is closed), and $F + G = \pi^{-1}(\pi(F))$ is closed as the preimage of a closed set in $E/G$.

An alternative method:

We can without loss of generality assume that $F \cap G = \{0\}$. Otherwise let $F'$ be a complement of $F\cap G$ in $F$ and consider $F'$ instead of $F$. Since $F' + G = F + G$ the result is unaffected.

Consider the space $H = F \oplus G$ with the norm $\lVert (f,g)\rVert_H = \lVert f\rVert_E + \lVert g\rVert_E$. It is easy to see that $\alpha \colon H \to E;\; \alpha((f,g)) = f+g$ is continuous. Using the finite-dimensionality of $F$, it is not hard to show that $\alpha$ is an embedding, there is a $\delta > 0$ with

$$\lVert f + g\rVert_E \geqslant \delta\cdot \lVert (f,g)\rVert_H.$$

(If there weren't, you'd have a sequence $p_n$ with $\lVert p_n\rVert_H = 1$ and $\lVert \alpha(p_n)\rVert_E \to 0$. Use the finite-dimensionality of $F$ to obtain a contradiction.)

Then, if $x \in \overline{F+G}$, you have a sequence $x_n \in F+G$ converging to $x$. Using the fact that $\alpha$ is an embedding, conclude that $x \in F+G$.

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer, after some thought this makes sense. Is there any other way of doing it? I'm just wondering as I would be surprised if this was the method my professor had in mind - our context for the exercise doesn't coincide with your approach.

Comment: Took a bit of thinking, but I came up with another way that's not too beastly. If that's still not fitting to the context, what is the context?

Comment: What is the canonical map? Is it $\pi: E \to E / G, \ e \mapsto [e]$, where $[e]$ denotes the equivalence class of $e$?

Comment: Why is $E / G$ finite dimensional? And how can $\pi^{-1}(\pi(F)) = F + G$ why isn't it just $F$?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Yes, that's the canonical map. Note that $\pi(e + g) = \pi(e)$ for every $e \in E$ and every $g \in G$, therefore $\pi^{-1}\bigl(\pi(S)\bigr) = S + G$ for every _subset_ (not only _subspace_) $S$ of $E$. And finally, it's in general not $E/G$ that is finite-dimensional, but $\pi(F)$ is a finite-dimensional subspace of $E/G$, as the image of a finite-dimensional subspace under a linear map.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach:

Start with the case where $F$ is one-dimensional: $F = \mathbb{R}x$.  If $x \in G$ there is nothing to show, so suppose $x \notin G$.  By the Hahn-Banach theorem, there is a continuous linear functional $f$ with $f(G) = 0$ and (after rescaling) $f(x)=1$.  Now suppose $y_n := g_n + c_n x \to y$.  We have $c_n = f(y_n) \to f(y)$ so $c_n$ converges to $c = f(y)$.  Then $g_n = y_n - c_n x \to y - cx$.  $G$ is closed so $y - cx \in G$, hence $y = (y-cx) + cx \in G + \mathbb{R}x$.

For the general case, proceed by induction on the dimension of $F$.

I feel somehow like Hahn-Banach may be buried within Daniel Fischer's answer, but I don't see it so I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have a more constructive proof:

We use the following fact:

> Let $Y$ be a subspace of a normed vector space $X$. Then $Y$ is closed if and only if $Y$ with the restricted metric is complete.

Our proof is the following:

Obviously, $G+F$ is a subspace of $E$. To proof that it is closed, we proceed by induction. Therefore we can asumme without restriction that $\dim N=1$. Let $z\in E$ such that $F:=\left\{\lambda z : \lambda \in \mathbb{K} \right\}$ ($\mathbb{K}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) and $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=(g_{n}+\lambda_{n}z)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a Cauchy sequence in $G+F$. Then we have two cases:

1. $(\lambda_{n})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded. Then it contains a convergent subsequence $(\lambda_{n_{k}})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$. Then the sequence $(g_{n_{k}})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}=(x_{n_{k}}-\lambda_{n_{k}})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is convergent. If it is not obvious, the proof is as follows:

   > Because  $(\lambda_{n_{k}})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is convergent, $(\lambda_{n_{k}})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is Cuachy. Let $\varepsilon>0$, then there is $N_{1}$ such that if $k,s\geq N_{1}$, then $$\left|\lambda_{n_{k}}-\lambda_{n_{s}}\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2\left\|z\right\|}.$$
   >   For other hand, as $(x_{n})$ is cauchy,  there is $N_{2}$ such that   if $k,s\geq N_{2}$, then $$\left\|x_{n_{k}}-x_{n_{s}}\right\|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
   >   Therefore, considering $N=\max\left\{N_{1},N_{2}\right\}$, if $k,s\geq N$ then $$\left\|g_{n_{k}}-g_{n_{s}}\right\|=\left\|x_{n_{k}}-\lambda_{n_{k}}-x_{n_{s}}+\lambda_{n_{s}}\right\|\leq \left\|x_{n_{k}}-x_{n_{s}}\right\|+\left|\lambda_{n_{k}}-\lambda_{n_{s}}\right|\left\|v\right\|<\varepsilon.$$
   >   So, $(g_{n_{k}})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq G$ is Cauchy, then, by the fact mentioned at the beginning,  we have that $(g_{n_{k}})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is convergent in $G$.

  Therefore,  $(x_{n_{k}})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}=(g_{n_{k}}+\lambda_{n_{k}}z)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges (in $G+F$) because it is sum of two convergent sequences. Thus, $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence with a convergent subsequence in $G+F$, then  $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is convergent in $G+F$. Therefore, $G+F$ is closed.

$(\lambda_{n})_{nin\mathbb{N}}$ is unbounded. Then there exists a subsequence $(\lambda_{n_{k}})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}|\lambda_{n_{k}}|=\infty$. Since $(x_{n})_{nin\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded (by be Cauchy), it follows that $$\left\|z-\frac{1}{\lambda_{n_{k}}}g_{n_{k}}\right\|=\left\|\frac{1}{\lambda_{n_{k}}}x_{n_{k}}\right\|\rightarrow 0,\qquad n\rightarrow \infty.$$ Then $z$ is a limit point of $G$, as $G$ is closed, we have $z\in G$, thus, $G+F=G$. Therefore, $G+F$ is closed.